# bash check if all rows into files are equal to "number"

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a file that contains some numbers (one per row) which are populated dynamically by another program, like this:

```
0
0
234
455
0
```

I should create a simple echo when ALL ROWS into file are equal to zero (0), I have created this script, but it does not work correctly:

```
if ! grep -x -q "0" "file";
then
echo "At least one row is not zero"
else
echo "All rows are zero"
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to add an explanation of what "does not work correctly" means. Does it respond with an error message? Does it turn your ears green? What output does it generate?

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep -v` to search for any line that does *not* match the pattern.

```
if grep -q -v -x 0 filename
then echo At least one row is not zero
else echo All rows are zero
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

with `awk` you can terminate as soon as you encounter non-zero.  Might be important if file is large.

```
$ awk '$0!=0 {exit 1}' file
```

use the exit status

```
$ if awk '$0!=0 {exit 1}' file; then echo "all zeros"; else echo "nonzero"; fi
```

Comment: `grep -q` does that too.

Comment: yes in addition to `q`(uiet), I think it also means `q`(uick exit)